# How to instruct Inno Setup to install certain files on Windows XP only?

Tags: inno-setup

I have a working Inno Setup script.  Recently, I have a file (`example.txt`) to be installed on Windows XP only.  The file will should not install on Windows Vista and above.

How may I construct the Inno Setup script to do so?  I can't find any related function in `[Files]` section.

Comment: [Honestly it's time for a change](https://www.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/xp/default.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`OnlyBelowVersion` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=commonparams&anchor=OnlyBelowVersion) to specify that the file should be installed only on Windows versions older than Vista ([Windows 6.0](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=winvernotes)).

```
[Files]
Source: "example.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; OnlyBelowVersion: 6.0
```